# Is it possible to use an Oracle database for Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, database

We are evaluating Drupal 8, and one of our needs is to use Oracle as the main (and only) database.

Is it possible to use Oracle as the Drupal 8 database? Can be a problem with the external modules?

And another question: The database access layer in Drupal 8 is Doctrine, or module developers can use hand-written queries (so, MySQL dependant queries)?

Comment: Why you require to use Oracle for main Drupal DB?

Comment: Did you have any problems with using oracle? @mHouses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now no. only in Drupal 7 we have. 
Drupal 8 supports MySQL 5.0.15 or higher (or MySQL 5.1.30 or higher) with InnoDB as the primary storage engine, and requires the PDO database extension.
https://www.drupal.org/requirements/database

https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle -  drupal 7

see the here for further info the thread is postponed as of now

https://www.drupal.org/node/2037119